# How to put a component in Triggerfield popup in ExtJS?

Tags: extjs, sencha-architect

Is there any way to implement a component popup on Trigger Field click? For example, I have a Trigger Field, and I would like to display a Tree Grid when I click the Triggerfield. When I select a value from the Tree Grid, the Trigger Field also set the same value.
There's an example from Ext.Net that is similar to this: http://examples.ext.net/#/Form/DropDownField/Overview/

[image]

I use Sencha Arhitect 3 and ExtJS 4.2. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The current trigger field does exactly that. For example a date field shows a `picker.Date` instance.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm asking "exactly" how to make this happen. Do I have to subclass some parent class, or extend the triggerfield?

Comment: Extend `Ext.form.field.Trigger`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this.

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {   
    store: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['group_name', 'property'],
    data: [{
        "group_name": "Armed Clash",
        "property": "Border Clash"
    }, {
        "group_name": "Armed Clash",
        "property": "Militia Clash"
    }, {
        "group_name": "Smuggling",
        "property": "Fuel"
    }, {
        "group_name": "Smuggling",
        "property": "Humans"
    }]
}),
listConfig: {
    tpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate',
        '<ul><tpl for=".">',
        '<tpl if={group_name}>',
        '<tpl if="xindex == 1 || this.getGroupStr(parent[xindex - 2]) != this.getGroupStr(values)">',
        '<li class="x-combo-list-group"><b>{[this.getGroupStr(values)]}</b></li>',
        '</tpl>',
        '</tpl>',
        '<li role="option" class="x-boundlist-item" style="padding-left: 12px">{property}</li>',
        '</tpl>' +
        '</ul>', {
            getGroupStr: function (values) {
                return values.group_name
            }
        }
    )
},
queryMode: 'local',
valueField: 'property',
displayField: 'property',
renderTo: Ext.getBody()
```

});

Make list collapsible using js and add icons using styles.
Can refer this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gilsha/82TzM/1/

Or else use Ext.ux.TreeCombo, Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gilsha/ZvnaM/83/

Comment: Both the answers were correct, but I want to give you credit.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I firstly consider using some already existing component.

Base treepicker exists as bundled extension in ExtJS framework - [`Ext.ux.TreePicker`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.ux.TreePicker)

Another useful implementation of treepicker is user extension [`Ext.ux.TreeCombo`](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?198856-Ext.ux.TreeCombo)

If you want to create your own picker component it should extends from [`Ext.form.field.Picker`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Picker)
For inspiration how to create your own picker you can look into source code of [`Ext.ux.TreePicker`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/source/TreePicker.html#Ext-ux-TreePicker) or [`Ext.picker.Date`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/source/Date3.html#Ext-picker-Date) components.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone's answer, I found another solution: use the `createPicker` function of the `TriggerField`. For example, here's how I extend the TriggerField` for a Grid Picker:

```
Ext.define('Custom.view.GridPicker', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.field.Picker',
    alias: 'widget.gridpicker',

    requires: [
        'Ext.grid.View',
        'Ext.grid.column.Column'
    ],

    store: 'none',
    idDataIndex: 'id',
    nameDataIndex: 'name',
    fieldLabel: 'Grid Picker',

    initComponent: function() {
        var me = this;

        me.callParent(arguments);
    },

    createPicker: function() {
        picker = new Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
            floating: true,
            hidden: true,
            height: 150,
            width: 400,
            header: false,
            store: this.store,
            columns: [
                {
                    xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                    width: 95,
                    text: 'ID',
                    dataIndex: this.idDataIndex
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                    width: 300,
                    text: 'Name',
                    dataIndex: this.nameDataIndex
                }
            ]
        });
        return picker;
    }

});
```

Fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2fb 
This custom component accepts 3 config : store, idDataIndex, nameDataIndex; all of them needed to display data to the grid. I think you can base on this to extend your own picker, such as Tree Grid Picker :)

Comment: Would like to do this, but your fiddle it not working for me.  It's just blank.